# How do I join array into a string in ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have ARM template parameter which is string array (like below). How do I create variable which will be a type of `string` which is `join` of those values, that is `"dominos","boeing"`?

```
"parameters": {
      "clientObject": {
        "value": [
            "dominos",
            "boeing"
         ]
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string() function, e.g.

```
[string(parameters('clientObject'))]
```

If you don't want the square brackets you can use the `replace()` function.

Answer (score 1):

there is no easy way to my knowledge, the only working solution - using a loop of deployments, pseudocode would look like this:

```
{
    name: concat('deploy-', copyIndex(1))
    type: microsoft.resources/deployments
    apiVersion: xxx
    copy: {
        count: length(parameters('clientObject')
        name: yyy
        mode: serial // (don't remember exact name, not parallel)
    }
    properties: {
        parameters: {
            param1: parameters('clientObject')[copyIndex()]
            state: reference(concat('deploy-', copyIndex()).outputs.your_output.value
        }
    }
}
```

to retrieve it you would use:

```
reference(concat('deploy-', length(parameters('clientObject')).outputs.your_output.value
```

and in the nested template you would just get the current param1 passed to the template and concat it to the state (where state it the output from the previous nested template run)

if you know the length of the array (and its static) you can hardcore a concat function or (better) do a join outside of the arm template

Comment: It's crazy, it's 2021 and there is no `join` in ARM

Comment: feel free to ask questions, this is pseudo code, i tried digging up a proper example in my code but failed, if you cant figure it out - ping me, i'll look through my archive for an example

Comment: I just gave up on this and just pass this a parameter as concated string instead. Not worth it to invest into this. Just wanted to make sure people who use template have proper types for parameters but seems ARM is not designed to handle this situation properly

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a `join` function in ARM, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#join).

> ### join
>
> `join(inputArray, delimiter)`
>
> Joins a string array into a single string, separated using a delimiter.
> ...
>
> #### Examples

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "variables": {
    "arrayString": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ]
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "firstOutput": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[join(variables('arrayString'), ',')]"
    },
    "secondOutput": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[join(variables('arrayString'), ';')]"
    }
  }
}
```

> The output from the preceding example is:

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| firstOutput | String | "one,two,three" |
| secondOutput | String | "one;two;three" |